# ColdFusion retry connection to Azure Sql Database

Tags: coldfusion, azure-sql-database, coldfusion-10

We are connecting to Sql Azure / Azure Sql Database using ColdFusion 10 with Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.

How do we handle Azure transient connection faults?

Comment: Do the connections come back immediately?

Comment: Normally yes. Because in Sql Azure you have a primary and 2 secondaries, in a given moment the platform may decide to switch a primary with a secondary. In that moment connections are dropped. The recommended is to delay 5 seconds before the first retry, and they retry until you reach 60 seconds (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connectivity-issues/)